# How do I add custom HTML to the content of an archive page's posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, filters, archives

I have a plugin with a custom post type for courses. I want to customize the content inside of the archive page's posts **and style it**. I realize that the archive page is using `the_content()` to retrieve the posts' content, and I'm able to use the corresponding filter to customize it; however, it's stripping the HTML and not allowing me to style it. How do I get past this?

```
function eri_course_archive_content_filter($content) {
    if (is_post_type_archive( 'eri-courses' )) {
        $content = (strlen($content) <= 140)? $content : wp_html_excerpt($content, 140);
        $extra = '<div class="x-text">
                <ul class="x-ul-icons" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                    <li class="x-li-icon" style="padding-bottom: 1%;"><i class="x-icon-o-dollar-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #47c3d3;" data-x-icon-o=""></i><strong>Cost:</strong>  '.get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_post_cost', true ).'</li>
                    <li class="x-li-icon" style="padding-bottom: 1%;"><i class="x-icon-o-clock" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #47c3d3;" data-x-icon-o=""></i><strong>Time:</strong> '.get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_post_time', true ).'</li>
                </ul>
            </div>';
        return $content . $extra;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'eri_course_archive_content_filter');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the priority, there could be other filters being applied afterwards, i.e:

`add_filter( 'the_content', 'eri_course_archive_content_filter', 999 );`

If that doesn't work, check that `the_content()` is actually being called in your archive template, because for example:
`echo get_the_content();` will not apply any filters set on `the_content`

Comment: Thanks @tdk. I tried it and it didn't work, so maybe you're right about `get_the_content()`. Being that I'm doing this for a plugin, I'm not using a custom archive page. I am trying to access and manipulate the default content that any theme would use. Such as how post templates all call for `the_content()` no matter what the theme is. Is there a work-around for `get_the_content()`?

Comment: Or is there a hook that allows you to add stuff after `get_the_content()` inside the archive page posts?

Comment: `get_the_content()` currently only has one filter:


 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

given that this is an archive page and it might only show excerpts, maybe you're looking for:



`add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'eri_course_archive_content_filter' );`